# How sets z-index to Ext.Panel (ExtJS)?

Tags: extjs

I have problem with z-index (i think) in ExtJS.
While drag and drop element  from GridPanel to DataView I drop element over GridPanel and it dropped to DataView. 
But  DataView have place under the GridPanel, and this imposible!
Thx!
(problem in all browsers)

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried setting the z-index of your item to a higher order?
ie.

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'Request Failed',
    msg:"Error, The request was not found in the database",
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
});
Ext.MessageBox.getDialog().getEl().setStyle('z-index','80000');
```

Comment: This worked for me just as you described. I needed the message box to appear over the loading mask and this did the trick

Comment: @Bosvark Where does the `80000` come from? +1ed!

Comment: indeed, @Chesney Where does the 80 000 come from? Just a 'high' number?

Comment: @VDP you are correct, I just set to a very high number -- You can put in any number you want. 80K was just an example number.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows**

If you want to manage the zIndex for windows you can use the `Ext.WindowManager`. All windows are registered automatically to the window manager so you can do:

```
Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront(component)
```

or get the next zIndex

```
Ext.WindowManager.getNextZSeed()
```

**All floating components**

If the issue is with other floating components like the dragging stuff you can register the present components to a zIndexManager

```
var zIndexManager = new Ext.ZIndexManager;
zIndexManager.register(compA);
zIndexManager.register(compB);
```

Then you can do:

```
zIndexManager.sendToBack(comp);
zIndexManager.bringToFront(comp);
```

or manage it with:

```
zIndexManager.getNextZSeed();
```