# ExtJS Panel always "in front" / always "on top"

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Scenario description: I have a border layout with an ExtJS container containing one-to-many windows an a panel (acting as a Taskbar). I want the taskbar to be *always on top*. If a Window is *active* and consequently *in front*, calling [toFront](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-toFront) does not put it in front as expected.

The ExtJS [Windows](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window) which remain in front is within the `center` area of the [Border layout](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border), whereas the panel acting as taskbar is within the `south` area, as follows:

```
items: [
        { 
            xtype: 'maincontainer', id:'maincontainer',
            region : 'center'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'launchpanel', id:'launchpanel', 
            region: 'south',
            collapsible : true,
        }        
],
```

where `maincontainer` and `launchpanel` extend `Ext.container.Container` and `Ext.panel.Panel` respectively. This code is within the main container which is the only item in the ExtJS MVC application's `Viewport`.

**How do I get the `launchpanel` to be always in front / on top?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read in the meantime what appears *in front* is determined by the CSS [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property.

Then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424665/how-sets-z-index-to-ext-panel-extjs) about how to set the z-index for a panel. Hence I set the z-index for the Panel each time it is rendered by having the following snippet in the controller:

```
'launchpanel': {
    expand: function(panel) { 
        panel.getEl().setStyle('z-index','80000');
    },
...
```

Still, if anyone has a better way of doing the above, please share!