# Movable panel that stays in background while moving in ExtJS 4.2.1

Tags: extjs4.2

I'm trying to create a floating window and a floating panel. Panel is to hold shortcuts (as in a desktop) and the window is like windows in a desktop environment. I want to be able to move the window and the panel both but I don't want ever the panel to come forth on the window (not in any situation). And I'm trying to do this in ExtJS 4.2.1. Here's the sample code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    draggable: true,
    floating: true,
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    resizable: true,
    headerPosition: 'bottom',
    title: 'Desktop Shortcuts'
}).show();

Ext.create('widget.window', {
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    title: 'Window'
}).show();
```

This code's problem is that, when you are trying to move the panel, it will come forth. Is there anyway I can get rid of that?

**[SOLUTION]**

It was just enough to set the `floating` property of panel to false. Since it is mentioned `draggable` it does not need floating to make the panel movable. And by disabling the floating property it won't ever come to front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use extjs' z-index property to allow you to bring what you want to the front. You can use the z-index manager to register/manage your elements through it or you can set the z-index manually. A higher z-index should bring that element in front of a lower one.

panel.getEl().setStyle('z-index','80000');

[Sencha Docs - ZIndexManager](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ZIndexManager)

[stack overflow similar question (z-index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424665/how-sets-z-index-to-ext-panel-extjs)

Comment: Pure CSS `z-index` won't do as the ExtJS engine will manipulate it when user tries to move the panel (it will be brought forth even if it's in background). And I have no experience using `ZIndexManager`. Do you have an example on how to use it? Thanks.

Comment: My bad, I should have noted you would most likely have to use a manager.  Here's a link to more info on how to achieve what you want using "register", "bringToFront", and others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433925/extjs-4-always-on-top-window

Comment: I shall test this tomorrow but just to make sure that I got you correctly, what you are suggesting is that I should send my panel to back when it is released, right? Even though it could be a solution to my problem but I was hoping to find a solution more general. Like defining layers to contain windows where windows within the same layer can change order but a window in an upper layer would never exchange order with one from below layer. Or perhaps I'm asking too much!

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll find that functionality built in.  You could use the window or z-index manager to build that functionality yourself (perhaps) , but I don't know of anything like that built into Extjs directly. Here's the Sencha Docs info for the z-index manager as well http://all-docs.info/extjs4/docs/api/Ext.ZIndexManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I solved my problem in another way.

Comment: Glad to hear it! EDIT: just noticed you posted the solution in the OP. nice!